# ReactJS: fetch from api print not just one time

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I got a table, filled by data coming from my API, I'm learning React and come to the solution in several tries.

Now I got the data printed in my table, but, these data is repeated three times (as the rows number multiplied by row number).

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";

// reactstrap components
import {Card, CardHeader, CardBody, Row, Col, Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem, CardTitle, Button, Table} from "reactstrap";


// core components
import PanelHeader from "components/PanelHeader/PanelHeader.jsx";

class Registries extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            error: null,
            articles: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8004/api/articles/all/')
            .then(results => {
                return results.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                let articles = data.map((row) => {
                    return(
                        <tr key={row.id}>
                            <td>{row.id}</td>
                            <td>{row.name}</td>
                            <td>{row.category}</td>
                            <td style={{width:"106px"}}>
                                <Button size={"sm"} color={"warning"}>
                                    <i className={"fa fa-edit"} />
                                </Button>
                                &nbsp;
                                <Button size={"sm"} color={"danger"}>
                                    <i className={"fa fa-trash"} />
                                </Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                });
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    articles: articles
                });
                console.log(articles);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <PanelHeader size="sm" />
                <div className="content">
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={12}>
                            <Card>
                                <CardHeader>
                                    <Breadcrumb>
                                        <BreadcrumbItem><a href="/">Home</a></BreadcrumbItem>
                                        <BreadcrumbItem active>Articoli</BreadcrumbItem>
                                    </Breadcrumb>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col xs="10">
                                            <CardTitle tag="h4">Articoli</CardTitle>
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col xs="2">
                                            <Button icon="ui-1_simple-add" size="lg" color="success" outline className={"btn-block"}>
                                                <i className={"fa fa-plus"} /> Nuovo
                                            </Button>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </CardHeader>
                                <CardBody>

                                    <Table data={this.state.articles} responsive className={"table-hover"}>
                                        <thead className="text-primary">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Nome</th>
                                            <th>Categoria</th>
                                            <th style={{width:"106px"}}>Opzioni</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        {this.state.articles.map((prop, key) => {
                                            if(this.state.error) {
                                                return(<div>Error: {this.state.error.message}</div>);
                                            }
                                            else if(this.state.isLoaded === false) {
                                                return(
                                                    <div>
                                                        <i className={"fa fa-spin fa-spinner"}/>
                                                        <br/>
                                                        Caricamento...
                                                    </div>
                                                );
                                            }
                                            else if(this.state.articles) {
                                                return (
                                                    <>
                                                        {this.state.articles.map((prop, key) => {
                                                            return <>{prop}</>;
                                                        })}
                                                    </>
                                                );
                                            }
                                        })}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </Table>
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Registries;
```

Here is how the table looks like:
[image]

The goal is to get only 3 rows, as the API return

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling this.state.articles.map in another this.state.articles.map in your render function.

Try to refactor this part of code:

```js
{this.state.articles.map((prop, key) => {
    if(this.state.error) {
        return(<div>Error: {this.state.error.message}</div>);
    }
    else if(this.state.isLoaded === false) {
        return(
            <div>
                <i className={"fa fa-spin fa-spinner"}/>
                <br/>
                Caricamento...
            </div>
        );
    }
    else if(this.state.articles) {
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.articles.map((prop, key) => {
                    return <>{prop}</>;
                })}
            </>
        );
    }
})}
```

One of possible refactorings could be like this:

```js
{
    this.state.error ?
        (<div>Error: {this.state.error.message}</div>) :
        (
            this.state.isLoaded === false ?
            (
                <div>
                    <i className={"fa fa-spin fa-spinner"}/>
                    <br/>
                    Caricamento...
                </div>
            ) :
            (
                this.state.articles && this.state.articles.map((prop, key) => {
                    return (<>{prop}</>);
                }) 
            ) 
        )
}
```